# Installing postgresql 8.4 on ubuntu 9.10 error

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

After upgrading Ubuntu to version 9.10 and removing postgresql 8.3, I ran **apt-get install postgresql-8.4** getting the following messages:

Setting up postgresql-8.4 (8.4.2-0ubuntu9.10) ...
Configuring already existing cluster (configuration: /etc/postgresql/8.4/main, data: /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main, owner: 115:128)
**Error: move_conffile: required configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf does not exist

Error: could not create default cluster. Please create it manually with**

pg_createcluster 8.4 main --start

When running that command I get the error:

**Configuring already existing cluster (configuration: /etc/postgresql/8.4/main, data: /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main, owner: 115:128)

Error: move_conffile: required configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf does not exist**

The output of **dpkg -l | grep postgresql** is

```
ii  postgresql-8.4             8.4.2-0ubuntu9.10    object-relational SQL database, version 8.4 

ii  postgresql-client-8.4      8.4.2-0ubuntu9.10    front-end programs for PostgreSQL 8.4

ii  postgresql-client-common   101                  manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versi

ii  postgresql-common          101                  PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

Comment: Solved, followed this link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgresql-8.3/+bug/235379 answer #15 and it started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, followed this link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgresql-8.3/+bug/235379 answer #15 and it started